# Where to find source code for specific function in C++ standard library? (Visual Studio installation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking at files in my Visual Studio 2013 installation but I can't find a specific function.

Heres the function I'm looking for:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/

I'm trying to implement something similar but wanted to see the source code in the standard library but there are so many files in there that I can't find it. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Have a look in your installed programs directory (maybe C:\Program Files\Visual Studio XX), there should be a directory called "VC" for Visual C++ - have a search in there and you should be able to find the source for std library utilities.

Comment: Yeah I'm in there and in the set file, but cannot find the set function.

Comment: Mine is in `<VisualStudionInstallDir>/VC/include/set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to type your desired type of method, put the cursor on it then press `F12`.

```
#include <set>

...

std::set::era|se
             ^ Cursor; then press F12
```

Alternatively, you could use "Find References" which can be found when right-clicking on a symbol.